# Prove $U$ is closed under multiplication. Prove $U$ is not closed under addition.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Recall that a unit $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a matrix that has a multiplicative inverse. Let $U$ be the set of all units of $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$. Prove $U$ is closed under multiplication. Prove $U$ is not closed under addition.

What I have in my proof is:

We will now prove $U$ is closed under multiplication. We will prove this directly. That is, we will show the multiplicative closure of $U$. We will use a $2 \times 2$ matrix, and some real numbers $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ to get

\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   c & d  \\
  \end{array}

and
\begin{array}{cc}
   e & f \\
   g & h  \\
  \end{array}
We will multiply them to get 
\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   c & d  \\
  \end{array}

## \begin{array}{cc}
   e & f \\
   g & h  \\
  \end{array}

\begin{array}{cc}
   ae+bg & af+bf \\
   ce+dg & cf+dh  \\
  \end{array}
Since $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h$ are all real numbers and we know $ae+bg,af+bf,ce+dg,cf+dh$ are real number because real numbers are closed under addition and multiplication which proves $U$ has multiplicative closure, thus proving this part of the proof.

My prof has told me I have to prove this has a multiplicative inverse, and I must do this for all n x n matrices and not just 2 x 2 matrices. I am confused on how to do that so I was wondering if anyone could offer me assistance?

As for the addition part, I know I must add two matrices for $U$ and show the result does not have a multiplicative inverse, but I also do not know how to go about this. Can anyone please help?

Comment: It is possible to do a proof that looks at the elements of the matrix (the coordinates of the matrix), but it is going to be a mess. You can work with the property of being a unit directly and other properties of matrix multiplication, that were proven using the coordinates, but are simpler. If $U,V$ are units, then there are matrices $U^{-1}, V^{-1}$ such that $UU^{-1}=U^{-1}U=I$ and $VV^{-1}=V^{-1}V=I$, Then if you multiply $(UV)(V^{-1}U^{-1})=(U(VV^{-1}))U^{-1}=(UI)U^{-1}=UU^{-1}=I$. Check that also $(V^{-1}U^{-1})(UV)=I$. This shows that $UV$ has an inverse (is a unit).

Comment: Note how we used that matrix multiplication is associative. This, either was proven before, or you need to prove it. You can use coordinates for that. Ask away if you haven't seen it done.

Comment: Ah, for the example, you try some. What if you add $I$ and $-I$?